# Why cumulative sum is not being carried over in the following numerical integration to calculate the area bewteen two curves?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, sympy

Description:

In the following python code, I am producing a Gaussian PDF, namely p(y). I am trying to find the area confined between the curve and any horizontal line in the range of [min_p, max_p] through the method of rectangular summation. My main problem is in the implementation of the function that is supposed to calculate this area iteratively for any particular element in p array (as defined in the code) and plot it as a function of a given value in the above range.

Issue:

Code runs perfectly but it is not producing the desired monotonically increasing/decreasing function.

```
import matplotlib
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np


N  = 10                                         # Number of sigmas away from central value
M, K = 2**10, 2**10                             # Number of grid points along y and p(y)

mean, sigma = 10.0, 1.0                         #Mean value and standard deviation of a Gaussian probability distribuiton (PDF)
ymin, ymax = -N*sigma+mean, N*sigma+mean        #Minimum and maximum and spacing between grid points along y-axis
ylims = [ymin, ymax]

y = np.linspace(ylims[0],ylims[1],M)            #The values of y-axis on grid points
pdf = norm.pdf(y,loc=mean,scale=sigma)          # Definiton of the normalized probability distribuiton function (PDF)
min_p , max_p = min(pdf), max(pdf)              #The maximum, minimum value of p(y) 

p = np.linspace(min_p, max_p, K)                #The values of p(y)-axis on grid points                                                                                               


def Area(p):                                    #Calculating the area under the PDF for which probability is more than pj-value for a particular jth index in pj_array above
    Areas = []                                
    for yi in y.flat:
        for p_j in p.flat:
            Area = 0.0
            delta_y = (ymax - ymin) / (M-1)    #The spacing beteen grid points along y-axis
            if (pdf[yi] > p_j): Area += (delta_y * pdf.sum())
            else: Area += 0.0
        Areas.append(Area)
    return Areas

pyplot.plot(p, Area(p), '-')
pyplot.axis([min_p, max_p, 0, 1])
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: print `area(p)`, and you'll see it is not the 1D array you claim it is

Comment: Yes. I just noticed that. I am trying to see why it is not updating for any element of p. Would you recommend me to edit the question then?

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to read right now. Your traceback is messed up, and you have one huge paragraph at the top

Answer (score 0):

After making quite a few changes here is the code I think you are trying to produce:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import pylab as p 
%matplotlib inline


N  = 10                                         # Number of sigmas away from central value
M, K = 2**10, 2**10                             # Number of grid points along x and y

mean, sigma = 10.0, 1.0                         #Mean value and standard deviation of a Gaussian probability distribuiton (PDF)
xmin, xmax = -N*sigma+mean, N*sigma+mean        #Minimum and maximum and spacing between grid points along y-axis

xx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,M)                    #The values of x-axis on grid points
pdf = norm.pdf(xx,loc=mean,scale=sigma )          # Definiton of the normalized probability distribuiton function (PDF)


min_p , max_p = min(pdf), max(pdf)  
pp = np.linspace(min_p,max_p, K)                        #The values of y-axis on grid points                                                                                               


delta_x = xx[1]-xx[0]    # spacing beteen grid points along x-axis
delta_p = pp[1]-pp[0]    # spacing between grid points on y-axis


def Area(p):                                    #Calculating the area under the PDF for which probability is more than pj-value for a particular jth index in pj_array above
    areas = []                                
    area=0
    for i in range(nx):

        for pi  in pp :
            if (pi< pdf[i]): 
                area +=  delta_x * delta_p 
        areas.append(area)
    return areas

p.subplot(121)
p.plot(xx,pdf)
p.subplot(122)
p.plot(xx, Area(p), '-')
```

It shows the probability density functions and it's integral. 
The thing is that you don't need to actually add up little boxes of delta_x* delta_p. For each step in x (I changed your variables for clarity) you just need to add the rectangle delta_x * pdf[i].

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import pylab as p 
%matplotlib inline


N  = 10                                         # Number of sigmas away from central value
M, K = 2**10, 2**10                             # Number of grid points along x and y

mean, sigma = 10.0, 1.0                         #Mean value and standard deviation of a Gaussian probability distribuiton (PDF)
xmin, xmax = -N*sigma+mean, N*sigma+mean        #Minimum and maximum and spacing between grid points along y-axis

xx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,M)                    #The values of x-axis on grid points
pdf = norm.pdf(xx,loc=mean,scale=sigma )          # Definiton of the normalized probability distribuiton function (PDF)

delta_x = xx[1]-xx[0]    # spacing between grid points along x-axis

def Area(p):                                    #Calculating the area under the PDF for which probability is more than pj-value for a particular jth index in pj_array above
    areas = []                                
    area=0
    for i in range(nx):
        area +=  delta_x * pdf[i] 
        areas.append(area)
    return areas

p.subplot(121)
p.plot(xx,pdf)
p.subplot(122)
p.plot(xx, Area(p), '-')
```

To actually just do the integral above any given line p=const, you only need to subtract that fixed value from `pdf[i]` , and possibly add a conditional depending of what you mean with integral (subtract negatives or ignore them) in your particular context.

Comment: Thanks roadrunner for the clarification. Now, at least I understand what was wrong with the code. But, I am still not getting the function. It is supposed to be a monotonically deceasing function whose max is 1 and whose min is 0 over the range [0,1] for p_j. So, this is why I edited the question so that it describes the problem better than before. Thanks again,